# How to set 'active' for tr/row in v-data-table (Vuetify 2.0+)?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to set 'active' for row where is item with property **selected: true**.
Before i did it with **:active="props.item.selected"**, but now, in new verison of Vuetify it doesnt work.

```
<v-data-table
                hide-default-footer
                :items="views.BusinessOperationView.valueList"
                :items-per-page="-1"
                :headers="views.BusinessOperationView.headers">
           <template v-slot:item="props">
                  <tr
                    @click="uiBusinessOperationSelectionChange(props.item.businessOperationId)"
                    :isSelected="props.item.selected"
                    style="cursor: pointer"
                    :active = "props.item.selected">
                    <td><v-card class="pa-2 ma-2 body-1 text-md-center">{{ props.item.loadText }}</v-card></td>
                    <td>{{ props.item.businessOperationName }}</td>
                  </tr>
           </template>

</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
  <tr :class="{active: group && item.id == group.id}">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.grade }}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

This is how I do it for data tables with vuetify. The 'active' class could be customized to have a different background color than the default one.